# HTML/CSS : Custom ul list

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I have my list design like this image:

[image]

As you can see the text has a margin-left with the decorated blue dot plus the text is justify left .So my question is how can i custom ul list like the design, have margin-left and the last text justify-left with other text above.

P/S:This is what i can try to do.

[image]

```css
ul{
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 400;
  color: #2e3192;
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-top: 17px;
  list-style: square inside url("BlueDot.png");
}
li{
  margin-top: 17px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Finance Leases</li>
  <li>Operating Leases</li>
  <li>Installment Sales</li>
  <li>Cross-Border Leases &<br/> Leases Denominated in<br/> Local Currencies</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Share your css and html

Comment: Create a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) with your code, and append it your question.

Comment: Added the code ,thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
li{
margin-left:30px;
text-indent:-30px;
}
```

```html
<li>asdb asdb asdb asdb asdb asdb asdb asdb asdb asdb asdb asdb asdb asdb asdb asdb asdb asdb asdb asdb asdb asdb asdb asdb asdb asdb asdb asdb asdb asdb asdb asdb asdb asdb asdb asdb asdb asdb asdb asdb asdb asdb asdb asdb </li>
```

Answer (score 2):

here you are

```css
ul {
  background: #469eb4;
  width: 400px;
}

li {
  list-style: none;
  color: #2c3d95;
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 20px;
}

li:after {
  content: "";
  width: 5px;
  height: 5px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #2e3192;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0%;
  top: 40%;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Finance Leases</li>
  <li>Operating Leases</li>
  <li>Installment Sales</li>
  <li>Cross-Border Leases &<br/> Leases Denominated in<br/> Local Currencies</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
ul li {
    /* Bullet color */
    color: blue;
    list-style-type: disc;
    font-size: 16px;
}

.box {
   background-color: green;
   width: 200px;
   padding-top: 20px;
   padding-bottom: 20px;
}

h1 {
   padding-left: 20px;
   color: white;
   font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <h1>Hello World</h1>
  <ul>
    <li>Coffee</li>
    <li>Tea</li>
    <li>This is a long string <br/> break</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Edit your css accordingly, change font, font size, background color, font color etc.

Answer (score 1):

Use can use `text-indent`

```css
li {
  width: 100px;
  padding: 0 20px;
  text-indent: -0.88em;
}
```

```html
<li>text text text</li>
<li>text text text text text text</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<ul>
<h2>
Leases/Installations Sales
</h2>
  <li>Coffee</li>
  <li>Tea</li>
  <li>Coca ColaCoca ColaCoca ColaCoca ColaCoca ColaCoca Cola</li>
</ul>
```

And the css is

```
ul{
  width:200px;
  background:blue;
  padding:5px 10px 20px 35px;
}
ul h2{
  margin-left:-15px;
  color:#fff;
}
```

Fiddler link is https://jsfiddle.net/zkybhjdy/1/